# There is incorrect links to files in my react app, what can I do to fix that?

Tags: reactjs

When I use `npm run build` I get file index.html in build folder which I want to use. But, there is a problem with this file. Links to files are written not correctly.

For example:

```
<link href="/static/css/main.073c9b0a.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

There is no dot before first "/" and because of this browser cannot find main.073c9b0a.css file. And that happens with every link in html file, so the page is empty. Is there any way to make React build my app correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add to your package.json

```
"homepage": "./"
```

React build it for host on servers, like nginx. That why it has't dot for build